# Numbering the edges of a graph, and a lowest path problem

Tags: graph-theory

Consider a connected graph with $n$ vertices, such that any pair of vertices are connected with at most one edge.

For each edge we wrote a positive integer and for all the edges but one this number is fixed (it can not be changed), the last edge can be changed. The changeable edge can be changed any time, you can think it as for each path you can change its number.

For each pair of vertices consider the lowest path between them, i.e. the path, such that the sum of the numbers on the edges in the path is as small as possible. (The direction doesn't matter, since the sum is the same.)

Suppose that the sum of the numbers on the edges in these $\binom{n}{2}$ pathes are all distinct and not greater than $\binom{n}{2}$.

How many possible value does $n$ have if $n<500$?

I tried to explain as understandable as possible. It is from a Russian book named Olympiad graphs. I couldn't solve it, it seems pretty difficult and it didn't contain a full solution, only a number. So the solution must be: $45$.

This theorem might help: [A graph theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C5%91nig's_theorem_(graph_theory))

Comment: It looks like (I don't have proof yet) if $n$ is a square number, then it is possible.

Comment: The second paragraph seems confused between edges and vertices.  If there is a number on each edge, there may be some number different from $n$ edges.  You say the vertices are fixed, do you mean edges?

Comment: Yupp spelling mistake, sorry! But is it OK now?

Comment: I'm still confused, at 'and for $n-1$ edges this number is fixed ..., the last edge can be changed'. Is it that there are just $n$ edges or should it be 'for all but one edge the number is fixed'?

Comment: I am so difused, you are right again

Comment: Do you mean that any pair of vertices is connected by exactly one path? This question seems very confusing.

Comment: No, but there doesn’t exist a pair of vertices with more than one edge between them

Comment: But you said there are $\binom{n}2$ paths. I suppose this also implies that no two vertices can be joined by two distinct paths both with lowest weight sum. Is that correct?

Comment: A path can contain more than one edge. We are considering a path with lowest sum for each pair of vertices

Comment: Is my attempt at formalization of the question, below, correct?

Comment: https://www.komal.hu/feladat?a=feladat&f=A722&l=en

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer. Rather, this is an attempt at clarifying the question that is **way** too long for a comment.
Is this a correct 'formalization' of what is being asked?

---

Given two adjacent vertices $v_0$ and $v_1$, let $e=v_0v_1 = v_1v_0$ denote the edge that joins $v_0$ and $v_1$.
Given an edge $e$, let $w(e)$ be its weight.

If $v_0,v_1,\dots,v_n$ are vertices such that for each $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ $v_{i-1}$ is adjacent to $v_{i}$, then $p = v_0v_1\cdots v_n$ is a *path*.
If we let $e_i = v_{i-1}v_i$, then we may also write $p =e_1e_2\cdots e_n$.
For such a path $p$, let $w(p) = \sum_{i=1}^n\,w(e_i)$.

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph.
Given two distinct vertices $u,v\in V$, let $P(u,v)$ be the set of paths joining $u$ and $v$.
Let

$$P_{\min} = \{ p\in P(u,v)\,|\, u,v \in E \,\text{ are distinct and $\forall q \in P(u,v),\, w(p) \leq w(q)$}\}.$$

Given an edge $e\in E$, let $P_{\min, e}$ be the set of paths in $P_{\min}$ that contain $e$.

---

For which $n$ can we find a connected graph $G = (V,E)$ satisfying

- $|V| = n$
- any pair of distinct vertices in $V$ are connected by at most one edge
- each edge in $E$ has a positive integer weight
- there is an edge $e \in E$ and a function $f: P_{\min,e} \longrightarrow \mathbb N\setminus\{0\}$ such that $g:P_{\min}\longrightarrow \mathbb N\setminus\{0\}$ given by

$$g(p) =
\left\{
\begin{array}{cccc}
w(p)&&&p \in P_{\min}\setminus P_{\min,e}\\
w(p)-w(e)+f(p)&&&p \in P_{\min,e}
\end{array}\right.$$

is injective no greater than $\binom{n}2$?